# How to get, and display the biggest values from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone tell me how to get and display the biggest values from a database? I have multiple values in my database with the heading "gmd", but how would I get only the first 3 biggest ones to be displayed? How would I do it in this example:

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
}
```

Comment: Is your gmd field a number or string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the query to order and limit the results.

```
SELECT gmd
FROM account
ORDER BY gmd DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Use your fetch array to display all of the results.

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row["gmd"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a field containing strings:

```
SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH( gmd ) DESC LIMIT 3
```

For a field containing numbers:

```
SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY `gmd` DESC";

Answer (score -1):

you do like this:
Sorry this is the correct query

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC limit 3";
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `max()` is an aggregation across the whole table. It will return only one row, always.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed that you can get upvoted for such obviously incorrect answers. What is SO coming to? :(

Comment: @d03boy, it's crowd wisdom, does not mean it's the best answer but most people accept what they know.