# How to display other values, when a query is limited by 3?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Can anyone tell me how to display the other values, when a query is limited my 3. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655452/php-how-to-get-and-display-the-biggest-values-from-a-database) question I asked how to order and limit values, but now I want to show the others in another query. How would I go about doing this?
Here's the code I used before:

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If display all rows use like this :

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
}
```

If display all rows without that 3 rows use like this :

```
$query  = "SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3,1000000";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
}
```

Comment: Also consider these common constructs (skipping the `ORDER BY` clause for simplicity):
1) `sprintf("SELECT gmd FROM account LIMIT %d,%d", $s, $n)` to display `n` elements starting from `s`; or:

2) `sprintf("SELECT gmd FROM account LIMIT %d,%d", ($p-1)*$n, $n)` to display "page `p` of results", with `n` results per page (and page numbering starting at 1). This is a *very* common construct, used for general-case result pagination.

Answer (score 1):

if you LIMIT the resultset in the query you only get 3 rows returned.

if you want to show the rest, don't limit inside the query, but check the rowcount in your php loop

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3,9999999999
```

or may be you need [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+pagination)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT gmd FROM account ORDER BY gmd DESC LIMIT 3,10
```

Will skip first 3 values and display next 10 ones satisfying the condition. This is MySQL only solution though.